# Codeigniter form submit on same page ends in empty result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a controller which fetches data from a database and assigns that data to the view. This controller is Searchcontroller.

If I sumbit the form on the Indexpage view to the Searchcontroller everything works fine, the data gets fetched and displayed correctly.

The issue is when I try to submit the same form in the Searchview that is displayed by Searchcontroller. Then I get empty results.

**Searchcontroller**

```
public function index() {
  $this->load->model('Dbmodel');

  $data = array(
    'result' => $result = $this->Dbmodel->getSearch($this->input->post('okresselect'), null),
    'okresy' => $result = $this->Dbmodel->getOkresy()
  );

  $this->load->view('searchpage', $data);
}
```

**Indexpage view**

```
<form method="post" action="search">

  .. some code here

</form>  

Searchpage view

<form method="post" action="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

  .. some code here

</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't use use codeigniter form helper for your form's http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html and also autoload the url helper in autoload.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try

Comment: no help, it still won't display any results..

Comment: Using form helper will make it easier rather than doing what you did in form action. Did you set your base url in config.php if your using codeigniter 3 if you did not set your base url some times you will have form submit issue. CodeIgniter also has form validation library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

the action in the form should look like  with the last trailing slash. now everything works correctly.

Thanks anyway guys!